# NONLINEAR ENERGY MINIMIZATION EXAMPLE

Tags: optimization, finite-element, linear-solver, nonlinear-equations

I am learning about FEM methods and nonlinear optimization. I would like to try my nonlinear trust region solver on some simple nonlinear problem.

What would be good example to implement for beginner? I am aiming to minimize nonlinear energy.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the minimal surface equation. Here is a version without line search or trust region: https://dealii.org/8.4.1/doxygen/deal.II/step_15.html

(Disclaimer: I am one of the authors of the library to which this program belongs.)